# Angular 2: show/hide div on app's main template from different components

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an Angular 2 app with several components:

```
- app
  - sidebar-panel
  - main-panel
     - obj-container (1)
     - obj-container (2)
     - (etc)
  - footer-panel
```

Basically, what I'd like is to show/hide the footer panel dinamically:

- When I double click on any of the objects inside 'obj-container' it should become visible. I want to do it from the handler of the Angular 'dblclick' event, inside each 'obj-container' component code.
- Inside its HTML template, the footer panel should have a close button to hide it.
- It'd be nice if both show/hide actions had an animation effect like jÇuery 'slideToggle' method.

In the template of 'app' component', the footer panel is inserted like this:

```
<div class="cell medium-3 footer" id="footerPanel">
  <app-footer-panel></app-footer-panel>
</div>
```

For now, the only way I think I can do this is by creating a variable on 'app' component and bind an *ngIf in the footer div to hide it or show it depending on its value. And, on each 'obj-container' component, create an @Output event that fires each time the user clicks on the close button and is captured by the parent 'app' component to modify the div visibility.

But, I think that this solution is too complicated, and also I miss the jQuery animation effect (although is not necessary, I'd like to know if I can get it).

Any ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are already on a good track with *ngIf. You can show and hide your footer with *ngIf. Like:

```
<footer *ngIf="showFooter"></footer>
```

and toggle showFooter value on dblclick on other components' buttons and footer closing button. To pass it from parent component to the footer(child) component, look Angular sources [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). Hint : @Input() is what you will need.
And for the animations, Angular has all you need : [here](https://angular.io/guide/animations)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the communication should be between the child components (obj-container) to the parent (app), who has the footer div. I'm trying to encapsulate the div inside the component, but I only get a blank div with no content. Perhaps Foundation framework doesn't like div inside Angular selectors... About the animation module, I had a quick look and I think it's exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: For the communication from child to parent you would need to use @Output and event emitter to prevent the parent of the changes.